# Каким образом мне встроить интерпретатор Python в приложение?

Tags: python, dll

Мне необходимо сохранить максимально возможную открытость кода(обычные py-файлы), и при этом сделать приложение независимым от наличия python на ПК пользователя. То, до чего я пока сам додумался - это встроить python полностью в файлы приложения и во всех файлах с кодом указать этот интерпретатор.

Но тесты показали, что это не работает. Тогда я посмотрел на ren`py - движок для создания визуальных новелл. В нем питон каким-то образом отражается в виде двух dll файлов. Каким образом мне можно сделать так-же?

Comment: А зачем вам это надо (может есть лучший вариан)?

Answer (score 1):

Встаивание питона описанно тут https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html . Есть ещё обвязки для разных языков, например,  я пользовался https://github.com/MeVisLab/pythonqt

Дллку для линковки бери в пакете python embeddable в загрузках на сайте