# Внедрение возможности кодить в игру, как это реализуется?

Tags: разработка-игр

В некоторых играх, как например в Space Engeneers, есть возможность *кодить внутри игры*. То есть можно написать скрипт, который задаст правила взаимодействия с некоторыми игровыми сущностями. Вопрос: знаете ли вы методы реализации подобной фичи? Как разработчики ограничивают возможности скрипта в игре?

Answer (score 1):

можно встроить Python с помощью его стандартных библиотек.
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1274803/Каким-образом-мне-встроить-интерпретатор-python-в-приложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1274803/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-python-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Я тоже хотел встроить, но на телефонах это выглядело ужасно неудобно.

Answer (score 1):

1. Есть огромное количество скриптовых языков встраиваемых в приложения. Конкретика зависит от вашего языка программирования и от конкретного игрового движка.
2. Возможности задаются (и ограничиваются) предоставляемым вами API (множеством объектов и методов, которые вы "даете" скрипту для манипуляций) и отчасти конструкциями скриптового языка.